# Multiple mapping of arrays within arrays - Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary, mapping

I want to go through an array in an array with arrays in those.

The array should contain 5 arrays, and in each of those arrays are five more arrays, the generation of the numbers is fine, but when I go through each of the arrays to map them with something else, I only get back an array with 5 arrays in it.

```
  def random_map
    @row = []
    @col = []
    @map = []
    5.times do |row|
      5.times do |col|
        @c = rand(3)
        @d = [@c]
        @col << @d
      end
      @row << @col
      @col = []
    end
    @map << @row
    @map.map! do |row|
      row.map! do |col|
        col.map! do |element|
          case(element[0])
          when 0
            element[0] = "BG"
          when 1
            element[0] = "B1"
          when 2
            element[0] = "TR"
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Anyone know what's up with the mapping?

Comment: Give an example of what your output should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive, but I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
def random_map
  Array.new(5) do
    Array.new(5) do
      Array.new(5) do
        %w{BG B1 TR}.sample
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Running it generates an Array of 5 Arrays of 5 Arrays of 5 Strings, chosen at random form the three strings `"BG"`, `"B1"`, and `"TR"`:

```
random_map
# => [[["B1", "BG", "BG", "B1", "B1"],
       ["B1", "B1", "BG", "TR", "B1"],
       ["B1", "B1", "TR", "TR", "TR"],
       ["B1", "TR", "TR", "BG", "B1"],
       ["BG", "TR", "BG", "TR", "TR"]],
      [["B1", "TR", "TR", "BG", "TR"],
       ["BG", "B1", "TR", "BG", "BG"],
       ["B1", "B1", "BG", "TR", "BG"],
       ["BG", "BG", "TR", "B1", "B1"],
       ["B1", "BG", "BG", "BG", "BG"]],
      [["B1", "BG", "BG", "B1", "TR"],
       ["BG", "BG", "B1", "B1", "TR"],
       ["B1", "BG", "B1", "TR", "TR"],
       ["BG", "TR", "B1", "B1", "BG"],
       ["TR", "TR", "BG", "TR", "B1"]],
      [["BG", "B1", "BG", "BG", "BG"],
       ["B1", "B1", "TR", "TR", "B1"],
       ["BG", "B1", "TR", "B1", "TR"],
       ["TR", "TR", "TR", "BG", "B1"],
       ["TR", "B1", "BG", "TR", "BG"]],
      [["B1", "B1", "BG", "BG", "TR"],
       ["TR", "TR", "B1", "BG", "BG"],
       ["TR", "BG", "B1", "BG", "TR"],
       ["BG", "B1", "TR", "BG", "TR"],
       ["B1", "TR", "BG", "B1", "B1"]]]
```

I'm specifically not using the instance variables `@row`, `@col`, `@map`, `@c`, or `@d` because it's not clear that you actually want to be setting them; it looks like you're using them as simply local variables.

Comment: That did indeed work. I did wish to set `@map` so I just added a `@map =` to the beginning, thanks!

Comment: @DarshanComputing Doing ` %w{BG B1 TR}` outside (before) the loops  is much more efficient, both memory-wise (less String objects) and time-wise.

Comment: @steenslag Indeed. I opted for simple and safe. If this is called only rarely, it hardly matters. It also seems conceivable that it may be desired/necessary to have separate String objects. (Who knows if they need to be mutated later? Perhaps unlikely, but certainly possible, and not clear from the question.) In any case, good point to bring up for OP in case this is a frequently called method and shared String objects are acceptable.